# What is the best way to test array of hashes with RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm trying to test array of hashes with RSpec, but I don't know how to test them because the hash order could change. E.G:

```
[{name: 'John', age: 40, country: {abrev: 'US', name: 'United States'}}, {name: 'Peter', age: 43, country: {abrev: 'US', name: 'United States'}}]
```

is the same as:

```
[{name: 'Peter', age: 43, country: {abrev: 'US', name: 'United States'}}, {name: 'John', age: 40, country: {abrev: 'US', name: 'United States'}}]
```

What is the best way to test them using RSpec? Should I use a custom matcher?

Answer (score 4):

You could use RSpec's [contain_exactly](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/contain-exactly-matcher) matcher, that doesn't care about ordering.

```
expect(collection).to contain_exactly(
  {name: 'John', age: 40, country: {abrev: 'US', name: 'United States'}},
  {name: 'Peter', age: 43, country: {abrev: 'US', name: 'United States'}}
)
```

Another option is to use `match_array`, which behaves similarly (order is not important), but the expected argument is an array, rather than individual elements.

```
expect(collection).to match_array([
  {name: 'John', age: 40, country: {abrev: 'US', name: 'United States'}},
  {name: 'Peter', age: 43, country: {abrev: 'US', name: 'United States'}}
])
```

Answer (score 2):

To test for array equality without order you could use:

```
expect(foo).to match_array(bar)
```

Or:

```
foo.should =~ bar
```